# contentType : 'application/json' not working for JSON String? [PHP]

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm new to JSON and tried some testing for passing an PHP Object to another site..
How does it come when I'm using *contentType : 'application/json'* the string can't be passed,
but when im unsing the default *contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'* it passes
the string and decodes it without problems?

Or do you use the application/json type only when passing an object but not a string?
Maybe I'm just missing something fundamental here..

**PHP OBJ**

```
$objectX = (object) ['name' => 'Here we go!','luckyNum' => 6,'rndText' => 'jkfid'];
```

**JS**

```
$('#btn1').on('click' , function(){
var json1 = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($objectX) ?>);    
    $.ajax({
        url : 'try.php',
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data : {
            json1 : json1
        }
    })
    .done (function(response) { console.log(response); })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {  alert('[Error ' + jqXHR.status + "] "  + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown); });
});
```

**try.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
$json1 = json_decode($_POST["json1"]);

echo "Player is: " . $json1->name;
echo "\nHis lucky Number is: " . $json1->luckyNum;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST request isn't "a JSON string", it is a JSON string encapsulated in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` message.

Either:

## Send an actual plain JSON message

Pass the JSON string to `data` instead of passing an object. Passing an object will make jQuery encode the content as form data.

```
data : json1
```

and change the PHP so it stops trying to read `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
```

## Stop claiming you are sending JSON

Remove:

```
contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the format looks like this:

```
var1=a&var2=b&var3=c
```

This is automatically converted to an array, accessible from `$_POST`.

However, `application/json` is a another text format which PHP won't parse automatically.
The text can be accessed by reading the virtual file `php://input`.

Another point however is that your request is also invalid.  You are sending a key/value pair as the body when the data is not expected to be associative.

In your ajax request, change it to:

```
data : json1
```

And in your PHP script use:

```
$json1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: I see, thanks! But how should I proceed when passing more than one object/string? Neither data : json1, json2 or data : { json1, json2 } seems to work

Comment: In that case there is no reason to encode it to use a json request.  Remember you only need to encode to JSON to convert PHP objects/arrays to a format compatible with javascript.  Right now there is no reason to expect JSON in the `try.php` file.

Comment: You can go with Quentins second solution since it better suits your usecase.  But also remove the `JSON.stringify` part, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it complicated, send it as a normal POST: [Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MwptTS)

```
<button id="btn1" type="button">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
// normal php object
$objectX = (object) ['name' => 'Here we go!','luckyNum' => 6,'rndText' => 'jkfid'];
?>

var json1 = <?php echo json_encode($objectX); // encode, no need for JSON.stringify ?>;
$('#btn1').on('click' , function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : 'try.php',
        type : 'POST', // send as normal post
        data : { json1 : json1 }, // just put a normal object
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then on the PHP:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $json1 = $_POST['json1'];
    echo "Player is: " . $json1['name'];
    echo "\nHis lucky Number is: " . $json1['luckyNum'];
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  However I do like the question since it educates people of HTTP behavior.

Comment: @Flosculus yes the OP's codes got messed up, made it more complicated and got confused on the flow

Comment: @Flosculus anyway i can't explain more than Quentin well, eloquently answered, had my +1 too

Comment: Ye I gave you that :P

Answer (score -1):

JSON starts with { and ends with }. Try to post well formatted JSON string, with comma between names

Comment: dataType is what you're expecting back from the server iirc.. im expecting text back, for now, not JSON

Comment: sorry, You're right. JSON starts with { and ends with }. Try to post well formatted JSON string, with comma between names

Comment: tried with **'{"name":"Here we go!","luckyNum":6,"rndText":"jkfid"} '** but both echo's remain blank with the json contentType, but not with the default